# How can I convert a char to CharSequence?

Tags: java

I want to take a char using charAt() from a string and want to search in another string using contains(). 
charAt() gives me a char and when I use contains() I need a CharSequence parameter to search that character in the second string.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: `Character.toString(yourChar)`.

Comment: In Java you would use [indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) where you can pass a character directly.

Answer (score 6):

A CharSequence is basically a string, you can concatenate an empty string with a char this will give you a string containing 1 char only.  You can also do String.valueOf(char here) or Character.toString(char here)

```
    String a = "abc";
    String b = "anthony";
    char c = a.charAt(0);
    b.contains("" + c);
    b.contains(String.valueOf(c));
```

Answer (score 4):

I give you an example:

Syntax of String `contains` method

```
public boolean String.contains(CharSequence s)
```

**Parameters**

String "e" − This is the sequence to search

**Return Value**

This method returns true only if this string contains "e" else false.

**Exception**

NullPointerException − if the value of the parameter is null.

Example

```
String yourSentence = "Hello world";
char yourChar = yourSentence.charAt(1);
String anotherSentence "Hello everyone";
boolean result = anotherSentence.contains(String.valueOf(yourChar)));
```

Answer (score 0):

as a one line :

```
stringToSearch.contains(Character.toString(aString.charAt(5)));
```